# In Excel: Return nth largest value in a group of numbers given constraints

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, rank

I was wondering if anyone could help with the following Excel question:

If I have three columns, Column A containing tweet texts, Column B containing the number of impressions that tweet has generated, and Column C containing the date of the tweet - I would like to output the following things without using VBA or pivot tables if I can:

- Produce a table with the top 10 tweets by impressions over a selected date range
- The table should have the tweet text in one column, and the associated impressions in the second column.

Essentially I want to look up the nth largest value given date constraints, and return that value as well as the tweet text alongside it.

I have been looking up the =LARGE(IF()) function but I haven't been successful so far, does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming 100 rows of data (change as required) and with required date range defined in `E2` (start date) and `E3` (end date), use this "array formula" in `G2` for numbers:

`=LARGE(IF(C$2:C$100>=E$2,IF(C$2:C$100<=E$3,B$2:B$100)),ROWS(G$2:G2))`

Confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copy down to G11

then in `F2` for text:

`=INDEX(A$2:A$100,SMALL(IF(B$2:B$100=G2,IF(C$2:C$100>=E$2,IF(C$2:C$100<=E$3,ROW(B$2:B$100)-ROW(B$2)+1))),COUNTIF(G$2:G2,G2)))`

Confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copy down to F11